# how to synchronize two posix process on two network machine?

Tags: c, linux, tcp, posix

I have two POSIX processes running on two Linux network hosts which are on the same subnet.
The two processes are the same and process A runs on host A and process B runs on host B.
The two processes must evolve a state machine in agreement for safety reasons. The two machines are not the same in terms of performance, machine A is much faster than B. Clearly to make the two processes communicate I have to use TCP sockets with a custom protocol for exchanging information. I would like to set up a mechanism to make the two hosts communicate  and to perform operations in a synchronous and in agreement.

Suggestions?

Comment: There's not all that much you can do here, other than setting 'checkpoints'.
Something like one of the two is 'the broker' and both processes send their progress to said 'broker'. And only after the 'broker' says: 'OK, continue', the two processes continue to execute.

Comment: Oh, there's some theoretical problem about, something with armies sending messengers to synchronise attacking time... Problem always: How can one be sure that the other one got the message? -> Confirmation message! But how does the other one know that first one received that confirmation message? Yet another message – and how does then first one know...

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Extending the army example: How can one machine actually know that the broker was able to successfully send a confirmation to the other machine as well? I don't think you gain anything by that broker – but you introduce additional communication overhead.

Comment: @Aconcagua I was merely giving my two cents on the matter. If I would have had a surefire way to solve the problem, I would have written an answer instead. :)

Comment: @Refugnic Eternium The operations of the state machine could be coded with a sort of counter, with a periodic time control. The broker idea is not bad, as long as the broker is managed by one of the two machines. I'm trying to build a good mechanism

Comment: You will have to make the two machines inform about their current states (or what they are going to do). The message should be somehow safe. I recommend including some kind of checksum in your messages to detect a bad value. A way might be sending some kind of *'I'm going to transition to state X'* message (confirmed or not), and machine will not transition until receiving the same message from its counter part.

Comment: @Aconcagua The problem is that in addition to the application states of the main state machine, all the operations of each state must be synchronized. For each operation, a message must be exchanged with ack. On both network machines I might need to use multiprocess solutions, but to synchronize the procedures I should be able to serialize the atomic operations. Could I assign a counter for single operations? I am trying to build a simple and safe mechanism to perform any operation in agreement. The final atomic operation could only be performed by a single machine, after both have decided.

Comment: If there are `n` processes (side note: it doesn't really matter if they reside on different or the same host apart from that you have additional communication means available on the same host – like shared memory) then the the *'I'm going to transition to X'* or generally *'I'm going to do Y'* approach appears nice: Either any process is aware of any other one and sends that message to every one of his mates – and state transition or action occurs as soon as all state machines have reached that point (n-1 neighbours sharing my own *'going to'* state).

Comment: With `n` processes then indeed a broker can get interesting: Every process only has a connection to the broker and that's all the process needs to be aware of – and the broker just accepts dynamically any process that's getting active, no matter how many there are of. It then can send a clearance message as soon as all FSM have published their intended transitions/actions. You might consider, too, some error handling mechanism (possibly including recovery) for the case that not all FSM are intending the same transition/action.